# R shiny: validate(need()) with dateRangeInput

Tags: r, validation, shiny

I've read the help pages and shiny webpages on `validate()` and `need()` 10 times, googled all variations I could think of, but I simply cannot find what is wrong with my code.

The only thing I require is for my app to show a custom error instead of the (empty) plot when a user inputs a wrong date range = 2nd date earlier than the 1st.

```
  output$plotTemp <- renderPlot({
    req(input$button) 
    validate(need(input$datums[1] < input$datums[2], "error: end date earlier than start"))
    isolate({buttonFeedbackServer("button", {  # if validate = ok, run functions
        importdata(input$jaartal)
        weerstation <- which(weerstations == input$weerstation)
        temperatuur(input$datums, weerstation) # create plot
        })
    })
  })
```

I get this error now: no applicable method for 'validate' applied to an object of class "NULL"

I bet it's gonna be something stupid, but I spent hours and hours on this without seeing it...

Without `validate()` everything works perfect, so it's no mistake in other code.

*My R, Rstudio and all packages have been updated last week.*

Comment: What happens now? Do you get an error message?

Comment: Ugh, so frustrated I forgot to add it. Edited my question!

Comment: try changing it to `shiny::validate` there are other packages that use that same function name.

Comment: Yup, that was it. Thank you SO much!
This might also explain why at a certain morning when I first opened the app at work, it suddenly worked! And then an hour later it didn't... and never did again. This made no sense whatsoever if I made a mistake in the code.
But now it does!

Comment: Are you using the `jsonlite` package? That package can trigger this sort of error for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Other packages, including `jsonlite` have a `validate` function. This error can occur when you accidentally are using a validate function from a different package. Try using `shiny::validate` instead to make sure you are using the correct `validate`.

Comment: And indeed, I am using `jsonlite` as well